# Why this challenge in Yu-Gi-Oh! 5D's Tag Force wasn't completed?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I was playing Yu-Gi-Oh! 5D's Tag Force in PPSSPP "PSP emulator for Android".

In this game, there are a [challenge list](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_5D%27s_Tag_Force_5#Challenge_list) to complete; one of those challenges is:

> - 001 - Caused 10,000 or more points of battle damage during a duel.

In a free duel against Tetsu Trudge, I was able to make the following battle damage by using these cards:

- Marauding Captain *(Monster effect)* - equipped with the following equip spell cards:
- Big Bang Shot
- Big Bang Shot
- Mage Power
- Mask of Brutality
- Swords of Revealing Light

**Turn 1**: Marauding Captain *(with the mentioned equip spell cards)*, attacked a face-down monster in face-down position - causing piercing damage due to "Big Bang Shot"'s effect.

**Damage**: `5300 LP`

**Turn 2**: other attack from Marauding Captain *(with the mentioned equip spell cards)* to a 2000 DEF monster in face-up position.

**Damage:** `5300 LP`

**Total:** `10600 LP damage in battle phase.`

I think I completed the challenge, but, once the duel ended, the challenge didn't show the text "indicating the challenged was completed".

Maybe I'm wrong, but, **why the challenge wasn't recognized?**.

---

Just in case I'm making it all wrong, can someone tell me how to complete these specific challenge?

N.B. I'm not asking for a deck building "I have a Maha Vailo's custom deck", but rather, how complete this challenge.

I tried also search on Google, but I couldn't find only but the challenge list rather than how complete such challenges.

Comment: I’m voting to close this as off-topic because it’s about achievements within a Yu-Gi-Oh! video game, rather than the rules of the game that are in common with the tabletop game.

Comment: @Thunderforge the way I see it is that OP is asking for an *interpretation of the rules, or some specific rules*, that they could have missed that explain why such achievement was not able to be completed. Under that light I see this as a valid YuGiOh question (also included an answer). Furthermore, let's remember that [questions about the computer version of a game are on-topic here](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1193/22373)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modify my "Maha Vailo's custom deck", I was able to make a `23400 LP` damage in a single attack during battle phase *(in the free duel mode)*.

However, after winning the duel, I didn't get any notification that indicated me I completed the challenge.

So, I tried complete this new challenge - which I haven't tried yet *(again, in the free duel mode)*:

> - 031 - Made your opponent run out of cards and won the duel.

Once I win the duel, I get this results *(in the duel results panel)* - "the image shows text in spanish, but the important part here is the red rectangle that says: **SUPERADO**" - or **COMPLETED**.

[image: Challenge 031 - completed]

I didn't get this notification when I win the duel by making the challenge #001, so, I follow these steps for check the challenge list:

> - Database > Duel Ranking

And, in the "Challenge" tab, I get this result:

[image: Challenge 001 - completed]

There you can see that the challenge 001 has a star on in - that indicates me the challenge was completed *(and the level of the deck used for complete the challenge)*<sup>1</sup>.

The same for these other challenges:

> - 031 - Made your opponent run out of cards and won the duel.
> - 036 - Won the duel using the effects of "Exodia the Forbidden One".

And you can see those challenges were completed - check the star alongside each challenge:

[image: Challenges 031 & 036 - completed]

With no other reliable source, I consider this answer as the correct answer for check when a challenge is completed *(even if in the "duel results" is not indicated whether a challenge was completed)*.

---

<sup>1</sup> About the level of the deck, I quote [this answer found on gamefaqs.gamespot.com](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/997448-yu-gi-oh-5ds-tag-force-5/58228932):

> the deck lvl. everyone has a deck lvl. **what ever the deck lvl is that
>   is what the challenge lvl well be**.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe I'm wrong, but, why the challenge wasn't recognized?

Perhaps this could be a bug on that game... but I suspect the reason was the following: ***you actually did 8000 points of damage, not 10600.***

The first hit your Marauding Captain did caused 5300 damage; that is true. *Your opponent's LP went from 8000 to 2700* thanks to that attack.

Now, **on your second attack you actually did... *2700 damage, and not 5300***. Why? Because on YuGiOh Lifepoints can't go negative. From the [rules on LP](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/LP):

> - If a player's LP would drop below 0, they become 0 rather than negative.
> - If a player's LP become 0, they lose the Duel.

This means that you did a net amount of damage of 8000, and not 10600 as it may seem.

In order to achieve the challenge, perhaps you will have to fight an opponent that gains LP, so when you win you would have made more than 8000 damage (and perhaps 10k to complete the challenge).

Comment: Just speculating, but perhaps it needs to be 10.000 damage with 1 attack?
It wouldn't be the clearest way of formulating the requirement, but it would explain why he didn't meet the challenge.

Comment: @kyudosai could be. However, the requirement reads "during a duel" so it means (or tries to mean) throughout the whole duel.